# Browsing a string in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to browse a string using javascript. Here I am only displaying the value of each characters in the string:

```
var value ="123#sometest";
for(var i=0; i< value.length;i++){
  alert(value[i]);
}
```

This works fine in Firefox, but in IE (6 and 7), this breaks. `value` exists, `i` exists, but value[i] is `undefined`.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the charAt() function:

```
var value ="123#sometest";

for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) 
{
  alert(value.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked! this is annoying that IE doesn't support [] :\